# How do I get the subscriptions of an Azure account via PowerShell when I am logged into Windows using a different account?

Tags: powershell, azure

When I execute `Get-AzureAccount`, I see the Azure account of the domain account I am logged into Windows with. So, when I run `Get-AzureSubscriptions`, I see the associated subscriptions. I want to get the subscriptions associated with a *different account* (one with which I cannot login into Windows) but I cannot figure out how this is done. Of course, `Add-AzureAccount` would seem to be the way to go but despite reading the TechNet help page on it, I don't see how another account can be added.

Thanks!

-Rohan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure subscriptions are stored in "C:\Users\%username%\appdata\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell" (or "%AppData%\Windows Azure Powershell) per user. The contents of that dir is an xml file containing the user's subscriptions. Each subscription is linked to a certificate that needs to reside in the same user's cert store in order to connect.

Anyways, using

`Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionDataFile <path to the other user's xml file>`

you should be able to read those subscriptions, if you have access to his/her profile folder (which would require local admin permissions on a normal system).